# How to create vector on the fly and store it as vector of pointers?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I want to create vector on the fly and store it inside another vector as pointers. I am trying below 2 approaches.

Approach 1:  (crashing while accessing)

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> *> vecofvec;
std::vector<int> temp;
vecofvec.push_back(&temp);
```

Approach 2:  (Working)

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> *> vecofvec;
vecofvec.push_back(new std::vector<int>);
```

I understand that first one is crashing because the vector i am creating is local and going out of scope but
I want to know if there is any way to avoid new (dynamic allocation) ? Also, i do not want to use smart pointers.

Comment: why do you want to store it as pointers?

Comment: @Albin Paul, I want to keep it efficient so i am not storing the vector itself because it copies whole vector which seems inefficent.

Comment: Don't tag C++ with C.

Comment: you need to store the whole vector<vector<int>> memory somewhere, either on stack or heap. If you use want to avoid copying then use emplace_back()
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back.

Comment: @AlbinPaul, How can i store it on stack ?

Comment: Useless use of pointers, std::vector already does its own dynamic memory managment.

Comment: "I want to keep it efficient so i am not storing the vector itself because it copies whole vector which seems inefficent." Frankly, this is cargo cult that you need to get rid of. Using more pointers does not make your code run faster. Using pointers *adds* a level or indirection but does not change the fact that you need to store the vectors somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The approach 1 is crashing because you store a pointer to a local vector that is destroyed after the function exit.

This creates vectors in the vector on the fly. You don't care of a vector life time.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vecofvec;
vecofvec.emplace_back();
```

> I want to keep it efficient so i am not storing the vector itself because it copies whole vector which seems inefficent.

This is wrong information. It does not copy, it moves vectors efficiently.

Comment: I tried the below code but it is crashing too
```
std::vector<std::vector<int> *> vecofvec;
std::vector<int> temp;
vecofvec.empace_back(&temp);
```

Comment: Don't store pointers, and don't develop programs with trials. See the first related link.